# Command line tool to delete folder with a specified name recursively in Windows?

Tags: windows, file, utilities, administration

I want to delete every "_svn" in every folder and subfolder...

For example

```
c:\
  proyect1
   _svn
   images
     _svn
     banner
       _svn
     buttons
       _svn
```

Then I run something like

```
rm-recurse c:\proyect1 _svn
```

And I should get:

```
c:\
  proyect1
   images
     banner
     buttons
```

The ideal thing would be a tiny stand-alone EXE or something like that.

--
Thanks Grant, as soon as I posted the question I saw [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29) documentation about the SVN export command, but I also want to delete the _vti_* folders stuff Visual Studio creates, so I'll also explore the `for` solution.

Comment: Please reword this in the form of a question; are you asking for help in developing a tool to do this, or do you wish to know if any such tools are available?

Comment: .bat files don't solve all Windows problems. Sometimes you have to fill them with commands and stuff first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554254/batch-command-to-delete-all-subfolders-with-a-specific-name/78174499#78174499 also provides a solution.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Similar to BlackTigerX's "for", I was going to suggest

`for /d /r . %d in (_svn) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"`

Comment: Yes, because the nature of this "for" is that it adds "_svn" to every directory entry as it recurses the directory tree.

Comment: Your solution bypasses that by returning an explicit list of the existing directories.

Comment: Though this is older than 2 years old, you taught me something new! Thanks.

Comment: @JMD If I wanted to target D:\Projects\ from a BAT FILE, how would you place a specific dir path into this command?

Comment: @DavidKEgghead, just replace the '.' (current directory) with the directory you want to search.  Be sure to wrap it in quotes if your target contains spaces.  Thus, you would use: `for /d /r "D:\Projects" %d in (_svn) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"`  I often test these by replacing the actual 'work' with an echo first: `for /d /r "D:\Projects" %d in (_svn) do @if exist "%d" echo "%d"` so that I can see what things I'm going to affect.

Comment: When I run this recursively sometimes I get "the-directory-is-not-empty" Why so? What might the reason behind that?

Comment: If you want to save this to a bat file, don't forget to replace % by %%.

Comment: @JMD +1 for the answer. A good use case is recursive deletion of `__MACOSX` directories and `.DS_Store` files, if you have copied files from Mac OS to Windows OS.

Save following lines to `del.bat` file and double click to run it.

`del /f /s .DS_Store
for /d /r . %%d in (__MACOSX) do (@if exist "%%d" rd /s /q "%%d")`

Comment: what if the specific folder name contains space, for example `My Folder` instead of `_svn`? i tried escaping it within quotation marks but it dosen't work!

Answer (score 42):

Time to learn some [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) ;o)

```
Get-ChildItem -path c:\projet -Include '_svn' -Recurse -force | Remove-Item -force -Recurse
```

The first part finds each _svn folder recursively. Force is used to find hidden folders.
Second part is used to delete these folders and their contents.
Remove commandlet comes with a handy "whatif" parameter which allows to preview what will be done.

PowerShell is available for Windows XP and Windows Vista. It is present on Windows 7 and on Windows Server 2008 R2 by default.

It's a MS product, it's free, and it rocks!

Comment: This solution works perfectly on windows server 2008 R2. Thank you

Comment: Does anyone know the syntax for the "whatif" parameter to preview what will be done?

Comment: Just add "-whatif" at the end of the line. It's an option of the Remove-Item Cmdlet

Answer (score 26):

For inclusion/invocation from within a BATCH file use (say for removing Debug and Release folder):

```
for /d /r . %%d in (Debug Release) do @if exist "%%d" echo "%%d" && rd /s/q "%%d"
```

double `%` are required within a batch file to work as escape chars. Else it reports error of syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

```
for /f "usebackq" %d in (`"dir _svn /ad/b/s"`) do rd /s/q "%d"
```

http://ebersys.blogspot.com/2008/07/recursively-delete-svn-folders-easy-way.html

Comment: I get an error: couldn't find dir file, I tried with cmd.exe /c dir ..., but i get the same error, however, JMD's solution dis the trick...

Comment: Oops, I checked the page you linked to, seems like there where a couple of ´´ (single quotes) missing... fixing that also did the trick...

Answer (score 10):

In Windows? If you are using tortoiseSVN you can use the export command to export a copy of the project without the .svn/_svn folders.

Comment: You can also do svn export with the command line tool whether you are on Windows or not.

Comment: I think the reason people end up needing to recursively delete the .svn/_svn folders is because they've directly copied their local working copy to a new location in order to do a folder comparison of their modified version compared to a clean export, i.e. after something goes awry with the modified local working copy.  (At least that's why I've needed it.  It's definitely easier/faster to just use 'svn export' when that's possible.)

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
import shutil

curdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

def removedir(dirname, name = ".svn"):
    if os.path.isdir(dirname):
        for file in os.listdir(dirname):
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dirname, file)) and file == name:
                thedir = os.path.join(dirname, name)
                shutil.rmtree(thedir)
                print ".",
            else:
                removedir(os.path.join(dirname, file))
```

I think you can try this Python script, which will work under any OS if you've got Python installed.

Answer (score 3):

Here... with FreeCommander or TotalCommander

http://www.broobles.com/blog/posts/36

socendani

Comment: As a long time TotalCommander (formerly Windows Commander!) user, I can't let this answer stay negative. This is a great, simple solution for someone who already has TC installed. I'm glad to have learned this nifty trick. Thanks!

Comment: The most straight forward solution here!

Answer (score 3):

Another option from [SVN Forum](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/31535-TortoiseSVN-export-by-command-line): use XCopy with a file that contains the list of files/directories to be excluded (.svn or _svn in this case)

```
XCopy C:\VersionedFolder C:\UnVersionedFolder /EXCLUDE:C:\No.SVN.txt /E /C /I /F /R /Y
```

Comment: Or `ROBOCOPY`, which doesn't require a list file.