# Command line to delete matching files and directories recursively

Tags: svn, command-line, file, recursion, dos

How can I recursively delete all files & directories that match a certain pattern? e.g. remove all the ".svn" directories and the files they contain?

(Sadly DOS only)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Since you're looking for a DOS solution, last week's post was almost identical and the consensus was:

[Command line tool to delete folder with a specified name recursively in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521382/command-line-tool-to-delete-folder-with-a-specified-name-recursively-in-windows/521433#521433)

> for /d /r . %d in (.svn) do @if exist
>   "%d" rd /s/q "%d"

or

> for /f "usebackq" %d in ("dir .svn
>   /ad/b/s") do rd /s/q "%d"

Actually, SVN also gives you the option to export a working directory without the .svn/_svn directories.

Afterthoughts, three years later:
I think the reason people end up needing to recursively delete the .svn/_svn folders is because they've directly copied their local working copy to a new location in order to do a folder comparison of their modified version compared to a clean export, i.e. after something goes awry with the modified local working copy.  (At least that's why I've needed it.  It's definitely easier/faster to just use 'svn export' when that's possible.)

Comment: "Actually, apparently TortoiseSVN also gives you the option to export a working directory without the .svn/_svn directories." I believe that is a feature of svn itself (`svn export`) not just TortoiseSVN, so any other client can do it too.

Comment: That was nice!  Windows Explorer didn't always delete the .svn stuff.

Comment: or try the hard core DOS variant suggested in http://superuser.com/questions/409479/how-do-i-recursively-delete-all-files-or-folders-whose-names-match-a-pattern-in

Comment: What I have to modify in this if I want to delete a file name recursively using this command ? currently this work only for folders

Comment: I've had more than one occasion where I needed to nuke all .svn directories because TortoiseSvn hosed the local repository, often as a result of the app crashing mid-operation, the user attempting to branch in a strange fashion, or the user misunderstanding Revert or Recover.

Answer (score 19):

Is this Unix or Windows? On Unix, an easy solution is

```
find . -name '.svn' -type d | xargs rm -rf
```

This searches recursively for all directories (-type d) in the hierarchy starting at "." (current directory), and finds those whose name is '.svn'; the list of the found directories is then fed to rm -rf for removal.

If you want to try it out, try

```
find . -name '.svn' -type d | xargs echo
```

This should provide you with a list of all the directories which *would* be recursively deleted.

Comment: I upvoted because I was looking for the same question, on Win32, but with gnutils installed -- so this worked perfectly for me. Man, pure-DOS is so crazy!

Comment: Upvoting - I needed a unix based solution to get rid of the awful eclipse .project and .settings files. Thanks! :D

Comment: Downvoting for wrong usage of `rm`+`xargs`+`find`. You should **always** use `-print0` and `NUL` termination in general in situations like these, otherwise it's just a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @Meltemi It's been a while, but 1) the question asks for a generic solution, the '.svn' was just an example that was given and 2) *nix filenames can contain almost anything except for a `NULL` byte and a forward slash in them. Whitespace is the harmful thing for this, an example with a space char in the name would be having a dir named `foo bar` somewhere in the hierarchy and a dir named `bar` in the current dir. Then you search for `foo*`, it feeds `some/path/foo bar` to `rm`, which fails silently for the first and deletes `bar`. See greyfade's answer below or use `-delete` for GNU find.

Comment: ok, starting to make sense. I needed to do something like this today and have no idea what the `-print0` or `-0` flags mean and having hard time finding documentation. on a Mac so many (most?) files/directories have space chars in them...so your comment piqued my curiosity.  #funwithunix

Comment: FWIW- For my needs I settled on: `find . -name '.svn' -type d -exec rm -rf '{}' +` cryptic as that may be, it works...

Comment: @Meltemi The important part to take from all that is that your shell doesn't escape things for you, when you pipe stuff, the target simply reads things from stdin -- there's other troublesome cases, `rm` is just the most obvious bad one. In this case, when there's a space, it's the same as executing `rm -rf foo/bar baz` -- once you write it out, it's obvious. Since Darwin (Mac) is technically a Unix, you should be able to find documentation on your `find` in the `man`, type `man find` in a shell. P.S. Your case probably acts funny if there's an apostrophe in the filename. :)

Answer (score 7):

If your files are in subversion, then doing an export from the repository will give you a directory tree with the .svn files and any other cruft removed.

Comment: Just be aware that the exported version will not contain any uncommited changes you may have in your working directory (for that you will need to commit then export)

Answer (score 6):

Something like this may do the trick, but of course be careful with it!

```
find . -name ".svn" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Try something like this first to do a dry run:

```
find . -name ".*" -exec echo {} \;
```

Note that the empty braces get filled in with the file names and the escaped semicolon ends the command that is executed (starting after the "-exec").

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

I needed to remove all "CVS" directories, so I ran a find . -name "CVS" -exec rm -rf {} \;

Answer (score 5):

On *nix or Cygwin:

```
find -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: Upvoting for only proper `find`+`rm` here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy it without exporting and eliminating the .svn from the projects, you shold use the /EXCLUDE option from XCOPY.

Like this:

```
xcopy /S/Q/EXCLUDE:svn.excludelist [path_from] [path_to\]
```

Observe the "\" (backslash) on the [path_to]. It determines that it's an output directory, so, xcopy will not question if it's a file or a directory.

The svn.excludelist is a text file containing the patterns to ignore on copy separated by line.

For Example:

```
.svn
.svn\
\.svn\
.obj
.o
.lib
\src\
```

And so on...