# Removing .svn files from all directories

Tags: bash, svn, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you remove Subversion control for a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154853/how-do-you-remove-subversion-control-for-a-folder)
>   [Command line to delete matching files and directories recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534798/command-line-to-delete-matching-files-and-directories-recursively)

I recently converted my cvs repository to svn using cvs2svn and I recently noticed that every directory has a hidden folder called .svn.  My current build script copies a lot of directories from my versioned resources directories and it ends up copying the .svn files.  Is there anyway to make svn not include these files when I checkout or do I need to write a script to delete all these .svn files.  There are many files that have these hidden .svn directories so this would be a pain unless I could write a recursive script to do this but I don't if I can do this for my windows installer.  Is there an easy way to stop svn from putting this hidden directory everywhere in my project?

Comment: Whoops, picked the wrong one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154853/how-do-you-remove-subversion-control-for-a-folder

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do a thing called an SVN Export to get the files without the .svn directories

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html

Comment: Yep, SVN Export will remove the .svn files.  You could make a batch file to run the export command from the command line and incorporate that into your build process.

Comment: check this link it helped me....  http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2010/09/script-to-remove-hidden-svn-folder.html

Comment: this is great, but unfortunately sometimes someone sends you a tarball full of them :(

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It actually doesn't anwser the question at all. If you don't have SVN at your disposal it's useless and if you do it doesn't *remove* the directories. It creates a copy of the existing files omitting the .svn files. Yes, I'm splitting hairs, but this is IT, right?

As per 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889619/command-to-recursively-remove-all-svn-directories-on-windows

running 

FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S *.svn*') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%G"

is a much better answer

Answer (score 70):

I'm not sure in your specific case that you want to remove all those .svn directories.  But if you do, here is a bash one-liner to do just that:

```
find . -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r
```

Comment: before running the command be sure to enter the proper directory, example:
cd mySVNdirectoryWhereToRemoveTheSubfolders

Answer (score 5):

I [posted this yesterday over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294590/how-to-remove-all-svn-directories-from-my-app-directories/1294808#1294808), but here is again because I kind of put it in the wrong thread anyway...

---

I've got something that should make your day. Original source is [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/24/shell-command-remove-svn-folders.aspx).

This is a (perfectly safe) Shell Extension that will add "Delete SVN Folders" to your right click menu in Windows. Run it on any directory containing those pesky files.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\DeleteSVN]
@="Delete SVN Folders"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\DeleteSVN\command]
@="cmd.exe /c \"TITLE Removing SVN Folders in %1 && COLOR 9A && FOR /r \"%1\" %%f IN (.svn) DO RD /s /q \"%%f\" \""
```

To make this part of your build script copy that call to cmd.exe and execute it.

Answer (score 5):

`find . -name '.svn' -depth -exec rm -rf '{}' \; -ls`

Comment: upvote for Windows users that have cygwin installed. Still I find using the File Explorer search box much easier.

Answer (score 5):

on Win32/Win64 systems, the following command should do the job:

```
del /q /s  .svn
```

Answer (score 4):

Those folders are required for how subversion works with a working copy (i.e. where you've done a checkout).

One option would be for you to do an export to another location. The export would not have the .svn folders, and you could run your script on that. Documentation: [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html), [TortoiseSVN Export](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html)

Another option would be to modify your script to ignore hidden directories, or build a better build tool.

Answer (score 3):

And a PowerShell version

```
ls  -Force -Recurse -Filter  .svn  | rm -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: Sometimes one inherits code where this is just more useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html) is what you want.  It will give you a clean copy of the code tree without the `.svn` directories (note that this copy is not under version control and svn commands won't work on it once it's exported).

I utilize this method to launch code on production servers.  Our build script takes an export of the code branch, tars and gzips it, uploads it to the correct server, and unzips/untars it.

Answer (score 1):

If wanna do this with ruby just paste my script at the root folder you want to remove recursively: http://fabianosoriani.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/ruby-script-to-remove-svn-folders/

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at `SVK`, which is a layer on top of Subversion. One of the advantages is that the repository metadata for your working copy, which is normally stored in the `.svn` dirs, is instead kept in a single central location, so you don't have the ugly hidden `.svn` dir problem. It's pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

find "/YourFolder" -name ".svn" -exec rm -fdR {} \;

Check this
[link](http://chandanshetty01.blogspot.com/2011/06/some-useful-scripscommands-which-i-use.html)

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if I would delete them, but maybe modify your build script to ignore copying them would be a good idea.  I use Ant to build compile and build my war and it does so ignoring .svn dirs.

Comment: Deleting them is not a good idea unless you want that folder to NOT be a working copy anymore.