# Remove .svn folders

Tags: svn

I am using SVN while developing a [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) site. Now I want to upload it to the server and there are loads of SVN files in `.svn` folders. Are these safe to remove and how do I remove them?

Comment: Since this question doesn't apply to WordPress itself but to development and deployment, I'm closing as off-topic and migrating it to Stack Overflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing .svn files from all directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301203/removing-svn-files-from-all-directories)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove Subversion control for a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154853/how-do-you-remove-subversion-control-for-a-folder)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You may also find the [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) command useful. This command exports a copy of your working tree without the .svn folders.

This comes pretty handy if you develop under the Subversion recommended tagging way, you can always export a tag, and then you'll have a better control over what revision is on production.

Comment: mod +1: Use `svn export` and create a clean copy for your wordpress site in another directory. If you remove the .svn folders, you can't update or use your workspace anymore. Thus, force to do a new `svn checkout` anyway.

Comment: additionally you can export only the last updated files spanning only the commits you need, very useful. Another thing I like to do, in CuteFTP, I set a mask so that CuteFTP will not upload .svn folders, useful when I do quick drag and drop uploads, bypassing export.

Comment: Note that svn export won't follow any symlinks that may exist in the repo, but will copy the symlink themselves over to the destination (which doesn't work well with relative symlinks..).

Answer (score 48):

```
find -type d -name .svn|xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the interesting part of the question.

Comment: On mac osx you have to change up this command a bit.  try this ... find ./ -name ".svn" | xargs rm -Rf

Comment: in the newly released svn 1.8, there is only a single .svn directory at the top level.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to delete all sub folders named **.svn** 
then create batch file with this content:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d *.svn') do (
rd /s /q "%%i"
)
```

save it in a file **del_All_Dot_SVN_Folders.cmd** . Run it. Your done.

Thanks to http://www.axelscript.com/2008/03/11/delete-all-svn-files-in-windows/

Remember the above code has .svn whereas the code in the link has only *svn so its better
to have the .svn to not accidentally have undesired effect.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to remove these directories, you will probably get troubles with your svn client. As a result, you have to do a new checkout of your repository.

Instead of removing these directories, you could exclude these from uploading with a filter inside your FTP program. I'm using Trasmit 4, which has support for this kind of functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the FTP exclude seems handy, will check if there is something for FileZilla.

Comment: Should be possible. Checkout the following [FileZilla Wiki](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Filename_Filters)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps exporting the folder is a better solution in your case. Exporting, excludes the .svn folders. If not, in mac/linux go to your terminal and type these:

```
cd /your/directory
find . -iname ".svn" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SVN checkout directory should always *keep* the `.svn` directories; that's how it communicates with SVN.

But any *copies* of your checked-out files - e.g. for packaging/uploading - can safely remove the `.svn` directories. They don't need the SVN-checkout data. To remove the `.svn` directories from these *copies*, simply delete them. (And see @Fernando's answer regarding svn export.)

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use the export-function from SVN and export your folder in itself and it will remove the .svn folder and uncouple it from the version control.

Reference: http://tortoisesvn.net/unversion.html