# android create ADT15 faild

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

why me create android AVD Faild?

remark:1. jdk installation 
 2. android sdk is for other PC to copy into this computer;

faild infromation:

1.at android virtual device manager windows form tips: an android virtual device  faild to load. click 'details' to see the error
2. when to create AVD error:
[2011-10-29 08:07:10 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI .svn to copy into the AVD folder.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue.  The problem is you're version controlling the `android-sdk` folder.  For some reason the Android Virtual Device (AVD) manager believes the .svn folder is specifying an Application Binary Interface (ABI).  It looks for userdata.img within the .svn folder and can't find it, so it fails.

I used the shell extension found in the responses for the question [Removing .svn files from all directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301203/removing-svn-files-from-all-directories) to remove all .svn folders recursively from the `android-sdk` folder.  After this, the AVD manager was able to create an AVD successfully.  Now I have to figure out how to get the SDK to play nicely with subversion.