# How to recursively delete all SVN files using PowerShell

Tags: svn, powershell

How would one go about deleting all Subversion files from a directory using PowerShell?

Comment: perhaps this isn't applicable, but it is possible to create a copy of your code from your repository without the subversion artifacts present. e.g. using TortoiseSVN, you can use 'SVN export'

Comment: maybe this helps https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-delete-all-the-tmp-files-on-a-drive/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you really do want to just delete the .svn directories, this could help:

```
gci c:\yourdirectory -include .svn -Recurse -Force | 
   Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Edit: 
Added `-Force` param to `gci` to list hidden directories and shortened the code.

*Keith is right that it you need to avoid deleting files with .svn extension, you should filter the items using `?`.*

Comment: is there a reason why we cannot recursively exclude the svn files while copying? I tried 
Copy-Item $source -Destination $dest -Recurse -Exclude '.svn'. But that didnt work. So I copied  it entirely and then removed the .svn files recursively using this command.

Comment: It doesn't work. I guess it is the same case as if you use `Get-ChildItem dir -recurse -exclude ..`. `-exclude` (and as I remember correctly also `-include`) doesn't play well with `-recurse`.

Comment: just in case someone finds this and has a similar issue. this answer helped me delete a ton of thumbs.db files and clean up my diff view. I like the alias better though "dir * -recurse -include thumbs.db | del -recurse -force"

Comment: When I tried it  the answer gci did not like the -force option - but still seems to have worked without it (Powershell 4.0)

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you don't want to delete any files that might also have .svn extension:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -r -include .svn -Force | Where {$_.PSIsContainer} |
    Remove-Item -r -force
```

Microsoft has responded to the suggestion in the comments below that Keith opened on MS Connect! As of PowerShell V3 you can do away with the extra (very slow) pipe to `Where {$_.PSIsContainer}` and use `-directory` instead:

```
gci $path -r -include .svn -force -directory | Remove-Item -r -force
```

PowerShell v3 can be downloaded for Windows 7
at *[Windows Management Framework 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595)*.

Comment: Yes, good catch :) However, I don't assume there is some file with this extension.

Comment: I've never used Subversion (just ClearCase & TFS) so I wasn't sure.

Comment: BTW I look forward to the day when you don't need `Where {$_.PSIsContainer}` and all you have to do is `gci . -r -containerOnly`.  I have my Get-ChildItem proxied to work this way but I can't count on other folks having it.  :-(

Comment: Have you added a suggestion about `-containerOnly` to connect? I would vote for sure.

Comment: I'd lose the wildcard on the pattern and just do ".svn" - otherwise you'll get folders that end with .svn

Comment: Stej, yes vote on it here: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/308796/add-enumeration-parameter-to-get-childitem-cmdlet-to-specify-container-non-container-both

Comment: Ah, so the directories aren't named like foo.svn, they are literally called ".svn"?  How about files?  Are there files called just ".svn" or do they have names like "foo.svn"?

Comment: Keith,  both you and stej included the -recurse argument in the remove-item cmdlet.  Is that really necessary?  I tried it without and it worked which seems logical since remove-item is going to operate on what it is passed through the pipeline?  But the fact that both of you included it in your example gives me pause.  Am I missing something or am I right that the second recurse is not needed?  Seth

Comment: I don't think it is needed.  I probably added it just out of habit.  :-)

Comment: @SethSpearman You can leave the -r out of the remove-item pipe, but doing so will result in an "are you sure you want to recursively remove items? [y] [n]" warning EACH time it recurses...so you are better off explicitly adding the -r.

Answer (score 5):

How about using [SVN Export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html) to get a clean checkout without .svn directories?

**Edit**

You might want to look at the answer here:

[Command line to delete matching files and directories recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534798/command-line-to-delete-matching-files-and-directories-recursively)

Comment: Cannot do that, this is code that is from other machine, it's a mess.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by stej is correct unless you want to delete all file with a specific string in their name. In that case, you should use:

```
gci "your_path" -include \*"specific_string"\* -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Notes:
`your_path` only requires quotes if it contains spaces or special characters.

`specific_string` requires quotes to make sure both wildcards are recognized, especially if the string includes characters such as `()`.