# Recursively delete folders with specific extension

Tags: batch-file, file-management

I have a file structure of images that is fairly flat although quite large (only goes 3-4 levels deep).  In this structure I want to delete all folders that end with '.files' (no quotes).

Note that the files I want to delete are hidden.

I saw a relevant question (linked below) that suggested the following batch file (except using '_svn')

[Command line tool to delete folder with a specified name recursively in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521382/command-line-tool-to-delete-folder-with-a-specified-name-recursively-in-windows/521433#521433)

`for /d /r . %d in (_svn) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"`

but it didnt work quite right for me. I got the following error when running at the directory I want to start:
`d" rd /s/q "d" was unexpected at this time.`

So to be clear, I'm looking for a command that I can put into a batch file which I can cd to my desired directory, run the command, and delete directories beneath the current directory that end in '.files'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f %a in ('dir C:\yourdir\*.files /b /s /a:hd') do rd /s /q "%a"
```

or if running it from a batch file use 2 `%`'s

```
for /f %%a in ('dir C:\yourdir\*.files /b /s /a:hd') do rd /s /q "%%a"
```

Comment: Oh, just realized that the files I want to delete are all hidden (didn't realize that meant they weren't normally accessible from the command line). How can I change this to work with hidden files? I'll edit the original question to show that. Thanks for the help, btw.