# Windows cmd which removes every bin and obj folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, batch-processing, windows-console

I'm trying to write a windows script that will remove every `bin` and `obj` folder in my project folder. It just doesn't work..

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521382/command-line-tool-to-delete-folder-with-a-specified-name-recursively-in-windows/521433#521433):

> for /d /r . %d in (_svn) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"

so I've tried:

```
for /d /r . %d in (bin) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"
```

but it didn't work. The closest I've been is:

```
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\temp\test\*.*") DO rmdir "bin" /s /q
```

it removes bin folder from first layer, but not in subfolders

Thanks for help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this:

```
for /d /r . %%d in (bin obj) do @if exist "%%d" rd /s/q "%%d"
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Create an empty file and name it *DeleteBinObjFolders.bat*
2. Copy-paste the below code into the *DeleteBinObjFolders.bat*
3. Copy the *DeleteBinObjFolders.bat* file in the same folder with your solution (*.sln) file.

> ```
> @echo off
> @echo Deleting all BIN and OBJ folders...
> for /d /r . %%d in (bin obj) do @if exist "%%d" rd /s/q "%%d"
> @echo BIN and OBJ folders successfully deleted :) Close the window.
> pause > nul
> ```