# Delete all node_modules subfolders

Tags: linux, windows, cmder

I'm doing a HDD upgrade, and while trying to backup my NodeJS projects i realize that all `node_modules` subfolders have over 1 milion files.

**So i'm looking for a way to remove all the `node_modules` subfolders and all their contents.**

The projects are located in :

```
C:/Node/App1/node_modules/..
C:/Node/App2/node_modules/..
C:/Node/App3/node_modules/..
etc..
```

My OS is Windows 10, but i can try either Windows or Linux commands because i'm using [cmder](http://cmder.net/), and it accepts both types of commands.

Comment: you can try rm -rf <folder name>

Comment: That works if i'm in the correct folder. But i need to search for all `node_modules` folders first and wipe out everything inside them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested this command in various situations and it seems to work fine.

```
for /d /r . %d in (node_modules) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"
```

I'm not sure how it works, it's an adapted solution from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521382/command-line-tool-to-delete-folder-with-a-specified-name-recursively-in-windows), if you need more details.

Answer (score 7):

For Linux:

```
cd Node
find . -maxdepth 2 -name node_modules -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
```