# Loop through tree and delete files and directories listed in variable (windows batch)

Tags: batch-file

I have the variable:

```
set "whattodelete=*xxx* *yyy* *zzz*"
```

and the following directory tree:

```
C:\Temp
  Folder1    Folder2    Folder3
    1aaa1      2aaa2      ...
    1bbb1      2bbb2
    1ccc1      2ccc2
    1xxx1      2xxx2
    1yyy1      2yyy2
    1zzz1      2zzz2
```

where 1aaa1 might be either directory or file.

I've read this:
[Command line tool to delete folder with a specified name recursively in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521382/command-line-tool-to-delete-folder-with-a-specified-name-recursively-in-windows/521433)

but can't figure out how to add loop for variable which contains many files/directories. I suspect that here might be one more inner or outer loop but I'm not so close with variable expansion. Could you help me?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48408403/edit) providing us with the script you have written so far, _not somebody elses question with different files, directory structures and several different answers_!

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask] and provide an [MCVE].

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `for /?` to get output the help for this command on several pages used for looping in Windows command environment. `for %%I in (%whattodelete%) do del /F /S /Q "C:\Temp\%%~I"` should work for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions 
set "whattodelete=*xxx* *yyy* *zzz*"
cd C:\Temp
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /b /s /a:d %whattodelete%`) do (
  rd /s /q "%%i"
  )
```