# Is there a way to delete all node_module without opening the every single project from local drive?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, command, node-modules

I have multiple project that uses `node_modules` which i didn't touched in month.
If i can remove `node_module` only that can save my 5 to 8 GB storage.

I found [Command line tool to delete folder with a specified name recursively in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521382/command-line-tool-to-delete-folder-with-a-specified-name-recursively-in-windows#521433)
  But that shows delete file in specific folder like

```
D:\Project\Doing\prject1\
D:\Project\Complete\Project1\

FOR /d /r . %d IN (project1) DO @IF EXIST "%d" rd /s /q "%d"
```

> But i don't want to search every directory to look for node_module instead i want to delete all the node_module folder from my PC (all
>   the drive) how can i do that?

If I need the node_modules back I can simply run `npm install` so clearing space is good idea for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://coderwall.com/p/guqrca/remove-all-node_module-folders-recursively) that worked like a charm.

`find . -name "node_modules" -exec rm -rf '{}' +`

Answer (score 1):

To list all your node_modules use this command in a command prom:

```
FOR /d /r . %d in (node_modules) DO @IF EXIST "%d" echo %d"
```

And for deleting you can do:

```
FOR /d /r . %d in (node_modules) DO @IF EXIST "%d" rm -rf "%d"
```

This will not work in powershell only cmd

Comment: I belive your command wild delete `node_module` inside `D` directory but  want to delete `node_module` from all directory `( D C E)`

Comment: I was able to find all node_modules on my PC with this command, but looked like you found a solution that worked for you :)